# Exactly how much is backported into RHEL [qemu-kvm specifically]? Only security patches, or perfomance improvments too?

Tags: redhat, kvm-virtualization, centos6

https://access.redhat.com/site/security/updates/backporting/?sc_cid=3093
http://froginapan.blogspot.com/2012/07/redhats-backporting-activity.html

As the above two links suggest, only security patches and certain selected "new" features and functionality is also backported.

My question is specifically regarding qemu-kvm and libvirt. If somebody knows for sure how advanced/ improved these packages are as compared to their "original" release versions, please share that.

> rpm -q --changelog qemu-kvm

...shows many backports/patches, but I don't know if new features are being added consistently as well.. May be someone who is following qemu-kvm development more closely would know...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously, not absolutely everything goes into RHEL, but all the security, stability and optimizations, if they pass QA, do. Considering the fact that libvirt, KVM and QEMU are all Red Hat sponsored projects, the porting happens quite naturally, because development happens with RHEL in mind.

If you want more information about specifics, just get in touch with a Red Hat SA, or ping the developers in the #kvm channel on OFTC

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK new RHEL features are only introduced on a minor release and not in security updates released between minor releases.

I'm pretty sure the package version will generally include a reference to the minor release in which it was updated.

```
rpm -q qemu-kvm
qemu-kvm-0.12.1.2-2.355.el6_4.9.x86_64
```

For example the RHEL [release notes for 6.5](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/6.5_Release_Notes/bh-virtualization.html#sect-kvm) describe the new features introduced compared to the previous minor release.